# SaveAs VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to auto-save a document with a specific file name followed by yesterdays date using the Now() function.

Every time I run the code I am hit with "Compile error: Expected: list separator or )" and I cant seem to sort the issue.

```
'Saves file as an xlsx in directory
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"P:\Desktop\Prior Day Journals\Tueday - Friday\Prior Day Journal" _
& Format(Now() –1,“DD-MMM-YYYY”)“.xlsx” _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

The issue always seems to be surrounding the -1 within the code which should be going back by a day for the file name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI you have two types of quotes in your code (`"` and `“`/`”`). Not sure if that's an issue with copy/pasting to here, or actually in the code.

Comment: @BruceWayne In fairness I think it was two different types from where I got some of the code from earlier. So a copy and paste issue before being on here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the error is that the `–` you used is not the minus sign `-` but the UNICODE character [EN DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

---

Another approach would be to use the [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251759.aspx) function to do so.

You also have a missing `&` in your concatenation string and a missing `,` to separate parameters.

```
'Saves file as an xlsx in directory
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "P:\Desktop\Prior Day Journals\Tueday - Friday\Prior Day Journal" _
& Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Now()),"DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsx" _
, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: There wasn't an issue with the way he had his date before. You can `Format(Now() -1, "DD-MMM-YYYY")` and it will work just fine. Try it in your Immediate window, you'll get yesterday in the proper format. The issues were just not concatenating the string, and missing the comma.

Comment: Both worked absolutely fine, but tried yours first @VincentG and it worked thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer, your problem came from using Unicode characters.